# Как конвертировать строку в число на js?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function sumCart(){
    //сумма все товаров
    if (!isEmpty(cart)){
        $('.sum-cart').html(' ');
    } else {
        $.getJSON('goods.json', function(data){
            var goods = data;
            var out = '';
            for(var id in cart){
                out +=cart[id]*goods[id].cost;
            }
            $('.sum-cart').html(out);
        });
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `out +=  +cart[id]*goods[id].cost;` так может быть ?

Comment: Можно так же конвертировать ее явно с помощью конструктора `Number()`

Comment: @MaximLensky не работает

Comment: @АлександрЛесив out +=  Number(cart[id]*goods[id].cost); вот так?

Comment: @MaximLensky out += new Number(cart[id]*goods[id].cost); так прописал, но все равно не работает

Comment: @MaximLensky Да но данные берутся из базы данных

Comment: @MaximLensky стоит тип данных int

Comment: @НикитаБаканин, конечно код `new Number(cart[id]*goods[id].cost)` работать не будет ведь вы преобразовываете в число уже после того, как строки были сконкатанированы. Вот так: `Number(cart[id]) * goods[id].cost`

Comment: @АлександрЛесив лучше ответом пишите и объясните  почему так

Comment: @НикитаБаканин, я понял. Вот что вам нужно `out = +out + cart[id]*goods[id].cost`

Comment: @MaximLensky ну я подожду

Comment: с плюсом не работает ?

Comment: Используйте `var out = 0;` вместо `var out = '';`. Сейчас Вы определяете `out` как строку

Comment: @АлександрЛесив спасибо, у вас сработало

Answer (score 1):

Замените:

```
out +=cart[id]*goods[id].cost;
```

на:

```
out += Number( cart[id]*goods[id].cost );
```

или:

```
out += +(cart[id]*goods[id].cost);
```

Comment: А зачем тут Number ? Умножение само преобразует операнды в числа. Проблема в начальном значении `var out = "";` К строке что не добавляй, будет строка. Должно быть `var out = 0;`